# function doesn't work as another function parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

[Failed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/62/)

[Original Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/61/)

Can anyone tell me how to pass the `draggable` function as a parameter for `clickit`, which is an AJAX function? I want to pass `draggable` as a parameter to attach it to a dynamically added element. I can't get it to work defining the draggable function and pass it to `clickit`.

```
function clickit(fun){
  $.ajax({
        'url' : "url",
        'dataType' : 'json',
        'success' : function(data){
         var item_html ="";
            $.each(data.query.results.json,function(i,k){
                item_html += '<div class="dialog"><h3>'+k+'</h3></div>'
            });           
            $('.area').html(item_html);
            fun;         
          }
   });   
}
$('button').click(function(){
    var funpara = $('.dialog').draggable();
    clickit(funpara)
});
```

Here's the one that works:

```
function clickit(){
  $.ajax({
        'url' : "url",
        'dataType' : 'json',
        'success' : function(data){
         var item_html ="";
            $.each(data.query.results.json,function(i,k){
                item_html += '<div class="dialog"><h3>'+k+'</h3></div>'
            });           
            $('.area').html(item_html);
            $('.dialog').draggable();         
          }
   });   
}

$('button').click(function(){
    clickit()
});
```

It looks like the parameter `fun` cannot be passed to the success function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to invoke `fun`, but currently you're just referencing to it without the invocation `()`

```
function (data) {
    var item_html = "";
    $.each(data.query.results.json, function (i, k) {
        item_html += '<div class="dialog"><h3>' + k + '</h3></div>';
    });           
    $('.area').html(item_html);
    fun();         
}
```

In your context, it looks like you want to invoke `$('.dialog').draggable()`, so `fun` should look more like this

```
function fun(o) {
    return $('.dialog').draggable(o);
}
```